# How does PropertyChangedEventHandler get hooked up in a UWP application?

Tags: uwp

I am working on a UWP app that uses DataTemplates with bound properties. In the event handler for the PropertyChangedEventHandler the PropertyChanged object is always null. Is there a way to debug why the PropertyChanged is always null? I have inspected the code and everything looks OK.

Comment: Can you share [mcve] for us ?

Comment: No I want some information on how to debug this myself. Are there any useful tools to debug problems like this or is it just a hunting expedition for these kind of problems.

Comment: You need check if  the  binding property is avaiable. Please go to live visual tree check the if binding  is valid.